# Model binding doesn't retrieve model data

Tags: laravel

I have this route:

```
Route::delete('product/{product}/attachments/{attachment}', 'AttachmentsController@destroy');
```

```
public function destroy(Product $product, Attachment $attachment)
{
    dd($product);
}
```

and `dd` shows:

```
App\Models\Product^ {#1059
  #fillable: array:3 [
    0 => "title"
    1 => "section_id"
    2 => "sortOrder"
  ]
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  ... etc
}
```

I can't access model data such as `$product->title` it will return `null`, so I tried to change `destory` method to:

```
public function destroy($product, Attachment $attachment)
{
    $product =  Product::whereId($product)->firstOrFail();
    dd($product);
}
```

and now I can access/see the model  data:

```
    "section_id" => 18
    "title" => "test product"
    "sortOrder" => 217645360
    "created_at" => "2020-05-05 13:34:54"
    "updated_at" => "2020-05-05 13:34:54"
  ]
  #original: array:8 [
    "id" => 18
    "section_id" => 18
    "title" => "test product"
    "sortOrder" => 217645360
    "created_at" => "2020-05-05 13:34:54"
    "updated_at" => "2020-05-05 13:34:54"
  ]
```

Why doesn't the model binding work? I even tried to add

```php
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    Route::model('product', App\Models\Product::class);
}
```

I tried also to do: `cache:clear` `route:clear`and `composer dumpautoload` I cant find why the model binding doesn't work?

Comment: is this the exact example or are any of the variable names different in the actual code? Also what version of Laravel are you on?

Comment: I think it's having issues due to `/product/{product}` (same name). Does it work with `/products/{product}`?

Comment: @AlexHarris its the same, I am using `Laravel Framework 7.9.2`

Comment: @TimLewis I have just tried to change the name, still same problem

Comment: try running `php artisan clear-compiled`

Comment: @AlexHarris same problem still

Comment: Okay, deleting `vendor` and doing `composer install` fixed this for me. I don't even know why this issue happen I didn't even upgrade or anything.